# Symfony user registration and add addresses

Tags: symfony4, php-7, symfony-forms

I want to create a Form to registration an user and his addresses (billing/shipping)
My Form contain UserEntity and two Address(Billing/Shipping)

In my User Entity, I want to save many addresses what user as save (to change address in cart) but keep addresses (billing/shipping) by default

Here is my User Entity

```php
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\UserAddress", mappedBy="user", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $addresses;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\UserAddress", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $billingAddress;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\UserAddress", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $deliveryAddress;
}
```

Here is my UserAddress Entity:

```php
class UserAddress{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="addresses")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;
}
```

Here is my UserRegistrationType

```php
$builder
    ->add('username')
    ->add('billingAddress', RegistrationAddressType::class, [
        'label'=>'billing Address',
        'required'  => true,
    ])
    ->add('deliveryAddress', RegistrationAddressType::class, [
        'label'=>'delivery Address',
        'required'  => false,
    ])
;
```

My form works perfectly, I have all the fields wanted.
But in this case, when I create a new User, I have an error on `address->user` because it's null.

How I can create an User, with his addresses in one form ?
How to check if user has check to use same address ? and set `user->setDeliveryAddress = billingAddress->getID()` to not duplicate entry in UserAddress ?

Thank a lot for help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on Many to One issue you can try to add in your address setters something like this:

```
    public function setBillingAddress(?UserAddress $address): self
    {
        $this->billingAddress = $address->setUser($this);

        return $this;
    }
```

and to your form address fields option `'by_reference' => false`.

What about billing and delivery addresses, you have on both One to One relation, if user have identical addresses and both fields in form will be filled, delivery address should be removed to avoid duplicates. You can check if the addresses match with the Symfony form or doctrine pre submit events. And your delivery address getter in user entity 
should look like this:

```
    public function getDeliveryAddress(): UserAddress
    {
        if (!empty($this->deliveryAddress)) {
            return $this->deliveryAddress;
        }

        return $this->billingAddress;
    }
```